# Secure connection between Unity and Google App Engine is possible?

Tags: security, google-app-engine, unity-game-engine

I want to develop an application for IOS and adndroid with unity.
My concern is how to be sure that only my application can get some secret data stored in the google app engine server. Is possible do this thing?
I try to explain the malicious scenario that I want stop :
-apply reverse engineering to my application (here I know that is impossible do something)
-contact my GAE webservice (here I want apply something to be sure that it is a maliciuos request) to get the informations

Please let me know if other information are needed

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

create an unsecured / simple ssl type connection and encrypt the data you send on it. 
using temporary shared keys for the duration of the connection should be about the best situation allowing you to "throw away a breakable key" after a certain time period.

From there its bog standard web request / sockets is it not?

I'm sure you can google foo something up for that!!!

Comment: I'm not talking about establish an ssl connection, as you know, GAE will allow you to specify which apps will be able to contact your webservices ( by inserting SHA1 Key and the package of the app ), would this be possible even for apps developed with Unity ?